# How To Create And Assign And Onclick Element To Another Element Created In JS

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, element

So, I am trying to make an element and then assign an onclick to it through JS.

Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
<div id = "Programs" onclick = "Cpb()">Programs</div>
```

JS

```
function Cpb() {
  document.getElementById("AllBody").innerHTML = "";
  var rh = document.createElement("h2");
  var rht = document.createTextNode("Recent Programs");
  rh.id = "Recentt";
  var rh1 = document.createElement("h4");
  var rh1t = document.createTextNode("test");
  rh1t.onclick = window.open('website');
  rh1.appendChild(rh1t);
  rh.appendChild(rht);
}
```

So does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This javascript worked for me:

```
let h4Node = document.createElement("H4");
h4Node.innerHTML = "4th Header";
h4Node.onclick = function (){
    alert('Oi!');
};
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(h4Node);
```

Html:

```
<div class="demo"></div>
```

It will put an h4 element with an `onclick` event listener inside the demo div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Example:

```
 rh1t.addEventListener('click', myHandlerFunction);

 function myHandlerFunction () {
   // ...
 }
```

You can continue using `onclick` as you have in your code. But you'll need to do as I've done above and assign a function reference to it. Like this:

```
  rh1t.onclick = myHandlerFunction;
  function myHandlerFunction () {
    window.open('website');
  }
```

Comment: What is handlerFunction?

Comment: Put any function there that you want. It is the function that will be executed when the element is clicked.